# VBScript is not working in Chrome but works in IE

Tags: javascript, vbscript, msxsl

i have a bunch of code in vbscrpt.I need to work this in both IE and Chrome.How can i make this function work in Chrome as well as IE

```
 <msxsl:script language="VBScript" implements- 
   prefix="mydetails">
 Function Getdetails(Val1 , Val2)
  Dim blnGetdetails
    blnGetdetails = ((Val1 or Val2) = Val1)
   If blnGetdetails = true Then
    Getdetails= "True"
    Else
    Getdetails= "False"
   End If
    End Function
    </msxsl:script>
```

Comment: simple: you can't. you can rewrite it in js though, it's only a couple lines...

Comment: How i can rewrite this function in js.. I dont have any idea about VB.

Answer (score -1):

Made as JS

`function Getdetails(Val1 , Val2) {`
    `If (Val2 == Val1){`
        `return true;`
    `} else {`
        `return false;`
    `}`
`}`